# Can I convert a Func<T, bool> to a Func<U, bool> where T and U are POCO classes where I can map properties of one to the other? If so, how?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a scenario where a method will take a predicate of type *Func< T, bool >* because the type T is the one that is exposed to the outer world, but when actually using that predicate I need that method to call another method that will take in *Func< U, bool >* where properties of T are mapped to properties of U.

A more concrete example would be:

```
public IEnumerable<ClientEntity> Search(Func<ClientEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    IList<ClientEntity> result = new List<ClientEntity>();

    // Somehow translate predicate into Func<Client, bool> which I will call realPredicate.
    _dataFacade.Clients.Where(realPredicate).ToList().ForEach(c => result.Add(new ClientEntity() { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name }));

    return result.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Would that be possible?

Please note that ClientEntity is a POCO class that I defined myself while Client is an Entity Framework class created by the model (DB first).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing did not require the use of Expression Trees:

```
public IEnumerable<ClientEntity> Search(Func<ClientEntity, bool> predicate)
{
    IList<ClientEntity> result = new List<ClientEntity>();

    Func<Client, bool> realPredicate = (c => predicate(ConvertFromClient(c)));        
    _dataFacade.Clients.Where(realPredicate).ToList().ForEach(c => result.Add(ConvertFromClient(c)));

    return result.AsEnumerable();
}

private static ClientEntity ConvertFromClient(Client client)
{
    ClientEntity result = new ClientEntity();

    if (client != null)
    {
        // I actually used AutoMapper from http://automapper.org/ here instead of assigning every property.
        result.Id = client.Id;
        result.Name = client.Name;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I once attempted this. It resulted in a not-too-bad working expression tree rewriter when the expression tree consist of the simpler operations (equals, larger-then, smaller-then, etc).

It can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/KyhwKHBJ).

You can use it as:

```
Expression<Func<Poco1>> where1 = p => p.Name == "fred";
Expression<Func<Poco2>> where2 = ExpressionRewriter.CastParam<Poco1, Poco2>(where1);
```

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't use lambdas - it uses [`Expression Trees`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)

```
Func<T, bool> lambda = ( o => o.Name == "fred" );
Expression<Func<T, bool>> expressionTree = ( o => o.Name == "fred" );
```

Expression Trees are in-memory object graphs that represent a given expression.

As they are just objects, you can create or modify them.

Here's another link: [`MSDN: How to: Modify Expression Trees`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx)